# Unable to ignore whitespace between text

Tags: regex, matlab

I need to ignore the spaces within the below pattern

> xx-xxx-xxxxx

where *x* is any number between 0 to 9. I have tried the following regex: `(\d{2}+)(|-)(\d{3}+)(|-)(\d{5})`. This was not working if any space is present in between, e.g.

> xx - x xx- xxx xx
>   xx-xxx-xx xxx
>   x x- xxx-xxxxx

I am using this regex in Matlab.

Comment: what do you want to match? is it 10 number of digits?

Comment: Yes 10 number with two hyphens in middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `-` is compulsion, you can use

```
[ ]*((?:[ ]*\d){2}[ ]*-[ ]*(?:[ ]*\d){3}-[ ]*(?:[ ]*\d){5})
```

or

```
\s*((?:\s*\d){2}\s*-\s*(?:\s*\d){3}-\s*(?:\s*\d){5})
```

In MATLAB

```
str = '11 - 1 11- 111 11 11-111-11 111 1 1- 111-11111';
expression = '[ ]*((?:[ ]*\d){2}[ ]*-[ ]*(?:[ ]*\d){3}-[ ]*(?:[ ]*\d){5})';
matchStr = regexp(str,expression,'match')
```

**Output**

```
matchStr =                                                                                                                                 
{                                                                                                                                          
  [1,1] = 11 - 1 11- 111 11                                                                                                                
  [1,2] =  11-111-11 111                                                                                                                   
  [1,3] =  1 1- 111-11111                                                                                                                  
}
```

For matching exactly 10 digits, you can use

```
((?:[- ]*\d){10})
```

Comment: One small question. It accepts the space before the start of the number. Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: @SimonC sorry, previous one was wrong..you can use `(\d(?:[ ]*\d)[ ]*-[ ]*(?:[ ]*\d){3}-[ ]*(?:[ ]*\d){5})`

Comment: @SimonC if you want, you can include **[word boundary](https://regex101.com/r/tI2dT8/5)** `\b` also

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save a lot of my time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can strip spaces from the string before you process it, so that your results are space-free.  Try this:

```
string = '99-999-99999 8 8 - 8 8 8 - 8 8 8 8 8 77- 777 -77777   6   6   -   6   6   6   -   6   6   6   6   6 BR-549 55-555-55555 rubber meets the road 444 - 444 - 44444';
without_spaces = regexprep(string, '\s+', '')
matched = regexp(without_spaces, '\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{5}','match')
```

The results:

```
matched =                                                                                                                                                                      
{                                                                                                                                                                              
  [1,1] = 99-999-99999                                                                                                                                                         
  [1,2] = 88-888-88888                                                                                                                                                         
  [1,3] = 77-777-77777                                                                                                                                                         
  [1,4] = 66-666-66666                                                                                                                                                         
  [1,5] = 55-555-55555                                                                                                                                                         
  [1,6] = 44-444-44444                                                                                                                                                         
}
```